# Laravel cashier with multiple model

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Currently on Laravel Cashier we can change a different model by using

```
CASHIER_MODEL=App\User
```

However, on my current need, I should be able to implement 1 time payment on User's table and Subscription payment on another entity which is Team's table. Anyone got an idea? User has many teams.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are ok with the user's payment. Your problem is on the team subscription.

Add a `team_id` column to your subscription table.

Add the Billable trait to your Team model.

Before creating a subscription or performing any operations using cashier change the `cashier.model` configuration.

```
Config::set('cashier.model', 'App\Team');
```

Now you will be able to perform every operation of the cashier for Team.

Answer (score 0):

The `CASHIER_MODEL` env var is used as `cashier.model` primarily to lookup the owner for a given subscription [see github code using "cashier.model"](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/search?q=%22cashier.model%22&unscoped_q=%22cashier.model%22).

You can still use the Billable trait on other models/objects (although be mindful of your schema/migrations and storing things nicely when interacting cashier).

For completeness, you could override [`Subscription::owner()`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/1ea8537d09264f0a06d8a73652268e3ee057ce48/src/Subscription.php#L63) and [`WebhookController::getUserByStripeId()`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/93567d1fb5f8f23b323647a4a160af32f9be3d1a/src/Http/Controllers/WebhookController.php#L214) methods with your own mechanism to differentiate billable models so that webhooks work nicely in return.

Depending on your application you could also make this part of the application architecture, such as billing the owner of a team, or abstracting your billable services to a consistent model that is responsible for individual and team billing.